# Dynamic variable names with JavaScript and constructor: cloning an image with EaselJS dynamically to multiple canvases

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, html5-canvas, easeljs

I'm attempting to use dynamic variable names in JavaScript applied to a constructor. It's been much more difficult than expected. I've read about this issue in numerous forums and webpages but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using a HTML5+JavaScript library called [EaselJS](http://easeljs.com/) but my problem it's not related to it but to JavaScript syntax! Here's my problem. I got this code:

```
stage1 = new Stage(document.getElementById("cnvs1"));
stage2 = new Stage(document.getElementById("cnvs2"));
stage3 = new Stage(document.getElementById("cnvs3"));
```

Here, the variables *stage* have assigned an Stage object which is initialized with canvas id *cnvs* This line (in the context of the rest of my code) works!

I'd like to simplify this to a single line with a for like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  //Of course this is wrong!
  stage[i] = new Stage(document.getElementById("cnvs[i]"));
}
```

[This link here](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/dynamic-variables-in-javascript) resumes how this can be done: With *eval* (a lot of people say it's not recommendable) and with *window* (recommended) Then if I do this (without the `for` to simplify even more):

```
var varname = "stage";
var i = 1;
window[varname + i] = new Stage(document.getElementById("cnvs_terminal1"));
```

The code still works. But I can't figure out how to accomplish a similar solution with the canvas id in quotes. These lines of code fail:

```
var i = 1;
var varname = "stage";
var varname2 = 'cnvs1';
var varname3 = "\"cnvs1\"";
var varname4 = "\"cnvs1" + i + "\"";

window[varname +i] = new Stage(document.getElementById(window[varname2]));
window[varname +i] = new Stage(document.getElementById(window[varname3]));
window[varname +i] = new Stage(document.getElementById(window[varname4]));
```

In these attempts even trying to pass the exact value I need (without the *i*) does not solve the problem. I'm backslashing quotes because I think they are necessary for the `getElementbyId`.

I'm certain there is a way to do this, maybe I don't know the syntax, maybe I don't know how to call variables with reference or by value properly, I don't know...

### Edit

I am trying @cHao's suggestion, but I can't do that either! Keeping it simple, I set the for for i to be one only:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 1; ++i) {
  //I use only one of the following lines at a time of course, but I'll write here my failing tries all together:
  stage[i] = new Stage(document.getElementById('cnvs'+i));
  stage[i-1] = new Stage(document.getElementById('cnvs'+i));

  //Hardcoding the first variable works!
  stage1 = new Stage(document.getElementById('cnvs'+i));
}
```

Half of the problem is solved, but what to do with the first variable?

### Edit 2

More detail has been requested. Here's a copy/paste example. Just update the EaselJS and an image paths for this to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="easeljs-0.4.0-26/lib/easel.js"></script>       
        
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      function init() {
        //MY PROBLEM LIES HERE!!
        for (var i = 1; i <= 1; ++i) {
          //This code WORKS
          stage1 = new Stage(document.getElementById('cnvs'+i));
          //This code DOES NOT WORK
          //stage[i] = new Stage(document.getElementById('cnvs'+i));
          //stage[i-1] = new Stage(document.getElementById('cnvs'+i));
        }
        var images = "images/itzapic.jpg";
        bitmap = new Bitmap(images);
        stage1.addChild(bitmap);
        stage1.update();
        Ticker.addListener(window);
      }
            
      function tick() {
        stage1.update();
      }
    </script>        
  </head>
    
  <body onload="init()"> 
    <canvas id="cnvs1" width="140" height="82">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you use arrays as suggested in your second code snippet.

Comment: Thanks @Kapil I did it but I needed guidance ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure i get the point of eval'ing or pre-figuring variable names and all that.  Seems like you could just do like

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    stage[i] = new Stage(document.getElementById('cnvs' + i));
}
```

`window["varname"]` won't help unless `varname` is global, and...eh.  You'll want to avoid globals if you can.  Either way, you don't need to escape quotes -- you don't need quotes in the name itself at all unless your IDs have quotes in them (which, AFAIK is invalid anyway) or you're eval'ing (which is evil in itself).

If you're looking to put the stages into an array (which seems like a better goal), you'll want your first stage to be `stage[0]`.  In which case, set `stage[i-1]` instead of `stage[i]`.

And if you're trying to set `stage1`, `stage2`, etc...stop.  Don't do that.  You have a bunch of items, that you're treating alike...that's the kind of thing arrays were meant for.  For one thing, notice how much easier it is to work with array elements than similarly-named variables?  I wasn't even seeing the issue, because with arrays it's already a non-issue.

As for your code...watch this.

```
stage = [];

function init() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 1; ++i) {
        stage[i-1] = new Stage(document.getElementById('cnvs'+i));
    }
    var images = "images/itzapic.jpg";
    bitmap = new Bitmap(images);
    stage[0].addChild(bitmap);
    stage[0].update();
    Ticker.addListener(window);
}

function tick() {
    for (var i = 0; i < stage.length; ++i) {
        stage[i].update();
    }
}
```

Once we switch from the `stage1` `stage2` brokenness to using an array, now we can have as many stages as we want.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to say in my question I tried that before, I'll edit my question with this. In synthesis I've already tried with no success! What could it be? =(

Comment: @Metafaniel: OK...what ***exactly*** are you trying to do?  Answer clearly and precisely.  Cause this is a pretty simple way to do what most people need to do.  If you need something different, then the change depends on how your problem differs from what i'm thinking it is.

Comment: OK! I'll clarify even more with a copy/paste example in a minute, thanks!

Comment: Ah.  Stop doing the "stage1" "stage2" thing.  Use an array like a real programmer.  :)

Comment: HEHE I know I know =P Thanks, but I just can't do this apparently simple task! I've added the example with your suggestion which it's not working =(

Comment: You can't do this apparently simple task because it's not so simple with a bunch of variables.  Watch this. (edited)

Comment: OH WOW!!! Great! I can see the image! But a little more code it's needed for this to run exactly as I want to, but it's almost solved! Wait...

Comment: I HAVE IT!! The very final code for what I needed to THANKS A LOT! I'll add it to my question as a reference! THANKS!!! You really helped me =D

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
var stagePrefix = 'stage';
var canvasPrefix = 'cnvs';
//adjust loop below based on your naming e.g. do they start at 0 or 1?
for(var i=1;i<5;i++){
  window[stagePrefix + i] = new Stage(document.getElementById(canvasPrefix + i));
}
```

Comment: HEY!!! This actually solves my problem! It works =D If only this way didn't create global variables =/ Could there be a way to accomplish this without using Window?? If no better answers come, you'll be the best answer ;) THANKS!

Comment: Your answer helped me too and solved my problem, BUT @cHao 's answer it's better because he's not using global variables as I did initially! Thanks a lot for your working answer too!! Thanks =)

Comment: Yeah I was going for the solution that matched your question... but as you've noted, using a single variable to contain all the references is better.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using an id with a numeric suffix to reference your canvases, I'd get them by tag name:

```
var canvases = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
```

Or, if you only want to process a certain set of the canvas elements on the page, give them a class:

```
var canvases = document.getElementsByClassName("cnvs");
```

Then, to get an Array of stages from your canvases, hijack the `Array.map()`* method:

```
var stages = [].map.call(canvases, function(canvas) {
    return new Stage(canvas);
});
```

---

*`Array.map()` is new to JS5, but if your browser supports `<canvas>` it supports JS5.  Regardless, here's the link to an [implementation of `Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility) you can use to support older browsers, in case you do have to support older browsers and you aren't already using a JS5 shim.

Comment: This sounds quite interesting and top edge coding hehe. I'll need to read more about it later, but I'm not certain if I can use it. I'm using Google Chrome 18. It supports this method??

Comment: @Metafaniel - Yes, it works in any version of Chrome. If your browser supports `<canvas>`, it certainly supports `Array.map()`.  You'll only have trouble with IE8 and IE7.  But, adding support for IE7 and IE8 is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

I'll post the final code for reference to someone who want to use EaselJS to render a single image in as many canvases as needed with the same object. For this you'll need the bitmap.clone() method and arrays for the stages. Thanks to @cHao for helping me out ;)

The following code will render the same image in all canvases. Update as necessary.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="easeljs-0.4.0-26/lib/easel.js"></script>       
       
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      stage = [];
      function init() {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) {
          stage[i-1] = new Stage(document.getElementById('cnvs'+i));
        }
        var images = "images/itzapic.jpg";
        bitmap = new Bitmap(images);
        stage[0].addChild(bitmap);
        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
          stage[i].addChild(bitmap.clone());
        }
        stage[0].update();
        Ticker.addListener(window);
        }

        function tick() {
        for (var i = 0; i < stage.length; ++i) {
          stage[i].update();
        }
      }
</script>        
</head>
    
  <body onload="init()"> 
    <canvas id="cnvs1" width="140" height="82"></canvas>
    <canvas id="cnvs2" width="140" height="82"></canvas>
    <canvas id="cnvs3" width="140" height="82"></canvas>
    <canvas id="cnvs4" width="140" height="82"></canvas>
    <canvas id="cnvs5" width="140" height="82"></canvas>
    <canvas id="cnvs6" width="140" height="82"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```